# Using kriging in R to extrapolate

Tags: r, interpolation, kriging

I have a very limited time series; Only 4 points are available.

```
    S<-c(81,78,72,65)
    x<-c(1,3,5,10)
```

S represents the survival rate, and t the time in years.

So far, I had used the nlm method to try and predict survival rate at t=20 with the following code:

```
  f<-function(ab){
   a <- ab[1]
   b <- ab[2]
   return(sum((((1+(x/a)**b)**-1)-S)**2))
   }

  minim <- nlm(f,p=c(1,1))

  ab <- minim$estimate

  a_opt <- ab[1]
  b_opt <- ab[2]

  prediction_exp <- function(x){
  return((1+(x/a_opt)**b_opt)**-1)
  }
  prediction_exp(20)
```

However, I recently discovered the Kriging method and I wanted to see if the predicted values would be very different with that obtained with the above method. How to I adapt the following code to be able to do what I am trying to do?

```
  model <- km(~x, design=data.frame(x=x), response=data.frame(S=S), 
        covtype="exp", lower=0.2)

  t <- seq(from=0, to=20, by=1)
  p <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(x=t), type="UK")

  plot(t, p$mean, type="l", ylim=c(-7,7), xlab="x", ylab="S")
  lines(t, p$lower95, col="black", lty=2)
  lines(t, p$upper95, col="black", lty=2)
  points(x, S, col="red", pch=19)
  abline(h=0)
```

Comment: Your code with `km` seems to work fine. If you're wondering why you're not seeing anything in your plot, it's because your `ylim=c(-7,7)` is wacky. Just remove that bit and you get your visualization.

Comment: Hi @Chu, Arh sorry I mis-read your post. Sorry, so why do you get a increase from 10 to 20? If you re-do your plot, plot(t, p$mean, type="l", ylim=c(0,100), xlab="x", ylab="S"), you get a downward trend